# Apache .htaccess : How to remove slash from directory end?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

How to remove slash from directory end?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^.+/$ %1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This rule doesn't work for directories. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to work.

Say you have a file `that` in two directories `/this` and `/that`. Those two directories are in an Apache root directory `/var/www/domain.com`

You're looking to turn the directory `http://domain.com/that/` to work as `http://domain.com/that`. But if you think about it, there's already (or could already be) a file `that` sitting in `/var/www/domain.com`. So if by your logic Apache allowed rewrites like that, it would only end up requesting the `/var/www/domain.com/that` file and not the original directory. If `/var/www/domain.com/that` didn't exist, it would just 404 as you're seeing now.